# two pairs of jeans Vs jeans

Tags: plural-forms

Which statement is correct and **Why**:

> There are jeans on the bed.
>
> There are two pairs of jeans on the bed.

The application I am learning on, said that "There are jeans on the bed" is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First all of all, it is usual to talk about "a pair of jeans" in English, but there is absolutely nothing wrong in referring to the garments as just "jeans". Note, however, that *jeans* is a non-count noun. You cannot refer to "one jeans" or "two jeans". If you want to count them, you have to refer to pairs of jeans.

This custom stems from the time when men's breeches (the precursors of trousers) and women's drawers (the precursors of knickers) came as separate garments, one for each leg, with both legs tied at the waist). They were therefore referred to as a pair of breeches or a pair of drawers, and this has carried over into modern-day usage when referring to trousers, knickers and jeans, even though they each constitute a single garment.

Because of this, all of the following sentences are grammatically correct:

> There are jeans on the bed

There is at least one pair of jeans on the bed.

> There is a pair of jeans on the bed.

There is exactly one pair of jeans on the bed.

> There are two pairs of jeans on the bed.

There are exactly two pairs of jeans on the bed.

However, the following would be incorrect:

> There are two jeans on the bed.

For the same reason, trousers, knickers, underpants, tights, etc, are all none-count nouns. If you want to count them, you have to refer to pairs of trousers, etc. However, *sock* and *stocking* are both count-nouns. Hopefully, you can work out why.